# Why doesn't my svg in react-native show any shadow?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

### The Problem:

I have a react native project which uses `react-native-svg` for importing my logos. I created my custom Bottom Tab Bar with `react-navigation` and it looks like this:

[image: My App]

So the problem is just I exported my svg when it looks like this in my adobe xd file (just the purple button):

[image: xd]

So you can see, there is clearly a shadow but not in my project. What am I doing wrong?

I use the component like this:

`import Logo from "../assets/icons/add_icon.svg"`

And then render it with `<Logo />`

Here is the svg (btw when I open it with browser it shows the shadow): https://pastebin.com/w9YZysgS

Why is there no shadow in my app? (also shadow styles won't work when applied directly).

**Specs:**

- Android
- Windows
- React-Native 0.62 (latest)

*Thank you very much in advance*

Comment: try putting your image inside a `<View>` with: The same height and width of your image, round borders like 2 * height of your image, and elevation between 7-10 maybe.
So it would look like: `<View style={{height: 10, width: 10, borderRadius: 20, elevation: 10}}> <Image src=(your image here) /> </View>`
[edit] Your svg, not image*

Comment: This works perfect. Here is how I set it up now: https://pastebin.com/6qdSNRXA
I put a View around my Icon and set props like you said and altough it doesn't look exactly like in the design, it still looks awesome and I can adjust the shadow with elevation value I guess. Can I set the elevation color?

Comment: Probably related: [SVG filter support in react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/150)

Comment: Read through all of it @Mehdi I think the TL;DR from all of that is just to use this: https://github.com/folofse/androw/tree/master/react-native-androw
I will try this out thx

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke I'm pretty sure you cant change the color of the elevation, sadly, but you can try with react-native-shadow: https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a coding fix, but before you could make the shadow a radial gradient object of the same shape as opposed to a shadow in the design.